# How to increase the PHP parameters using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to increase the following parameters to what is shown below:

```
max_input_vars = 10000;
suhosin.post.max_vars = 10000;
suhosin.request.max_vars = 10000;
```

I cannot do this in the PHP settings on my hosting company’s website and they have told me to do this in an .htaccess file.

However, I don't know how to do this. How do I set these values in an .htaccess file, please?

Comment: Did you try looking here? http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
php_value max_input_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 10000
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to put anything before or after that code?